# Can a UserControl be made Internal in WinUI3?

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3, winui

Is it possible in a WinUI3 application to have the following setup:

Assembly1.dll

- defines a XAML UserControl '`MyUserControl`' having '`internal`' access modifier
- specifies assembly level attribute '`InternalsVisibleTo('Main, PublicKey...")`

Main.exe

- references Assembly1.dll
- MainPage.xaml contains an instance of `MyUserControl`

I am familiar with using 'regular' (non-XAML) internal classes defined in Assembly1 within my Main.exe via InternalsVisibleTo. But I cannot seem to do the same with XAML user controls.

The effect I am trying to achieve is having a WinUI3 XAML Control Library assembly whose controls are only usable by specific other assemblies (namely, those within our own company). It is not an option to put 'MyUserControl' in Main.exe, because 'MyUserControl' also needs to be used by MyOtherMain.exe, but should not be used by 'SomeoneElsesMain.exe'

Comment: I'm afraid you can't. At least AFAIK. I'd create a NuGet for those internal controls.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewKeepCoding, that's what I was afraid of. 
By the way, since you mentioned it: What benefit is it to make a NuGet for those controls if the only developer-usage of them will be our internal team, and they will only be distributed in binary form with our executables?  Is the benefit of NuGet you suggest purely for distribution amongst our internal development team?

Comment: NuGet packages are easy to install and track versions if you do it right. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/overview).